# Basic authentication doesn't work at Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, basic-authentication

I work on a web application that uses basic authentication (Yes, I know it's horrible, not my decision).
When the browser try to connect the server answer with 401 response with www authenticate basic realm etc...
Well, with chrome everything goes as excpected, when the browser gets this 401 answer it asks the user to enter username and password and send to the server.
But on IE nothing happend. Just white screen.

I work with IE 9, visual studio 2010, .Net 4.

Does anyone have any idea that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/834489/internet-explorer-does-not-support-user-names-and-passwords-in-web-site-addresses-http-or-https-urls
Have you already tried this workaround?